# Using a concatenation operator with a ternary conditional?

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-operator

Is it possible to run two ternary conditionals, concatenating the results of the second to the first?

My conditionals read as follows:

```
$tr_class  = (!$pinned ?: "warning");
$tr_class .= ($read ?: " unread");

echo "<tr class='" . $tr_class . "'>";
```

If something is `$pinned` but `!$read`, I should get:

```
<tr class='warning unread'>
```

But I only get the `' unread'`? It seems like the second ternary conditional is overwriting the former, and not concatenating?

Is there away around this, without writing full if/else statements?

Comment: If `$pinned = true` and `$read = false` it shows `warning unread`

Comment: Same... my results show `warning unread` if `$pinned` and `! $read`

Comment: You're doing something else wrong @mpdc as that code works. [See this eval.in](https://eval.in/172990)

Comment: Could not replicate: http://ideone.com/D8Lna2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes is the short answer. If you could not concatenate the outputs of variables / invocation return values in PHP it would not have come very far as a language.

Your code works. I suspect the problem is with the values of `$pinned` and `$read` before it gets to your conditional statements.

If you neglect to put the 'is true' side of the ternary, it will take the value of the test which will usually be true or false, you should only leave this out if you want the 'is true' value to be the same as the conditional statement.

Comment: Running some tests and looking at the console, it looks like I needed to write a full `? "" : " unread"` for some reason, it didn't like the shorthand `?:` notation. Never had that issue before though.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. It makes sense why I was getting `warning1` as an output now!